# Java Constructors and Syntax involving the this operator

Tags: java

```
public Book(String isbn, double cost) {
  this.cost = cost; 
  this();
  this(isbn); 
}
```

What is wrong with this code? missing the periods after this(); and this(isbn); ?
Just want to confirm answer.

Comment: Not sure what the point of your question is. If you tried to compile this you would get several error messages.  And any questions would be answered by a basic Java tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

A call to another constructor (such as `this()`) must be the first statement in a constructor and multiple calls to different constructors are not allowed.